# In a PostgreSQL WHERE clause, how do I find all rows whose ID's are NOT in an array?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

Okay, I've got a stored procedure... how do I find all rows whose ID's are not in an array? (Keep in mind that I'm using a PostgreSQL array that is created dynamically when the stored procedure is created

Example:

```
|  people   |
-------------
| id | Name |
-------------
|  1 | Bob  |
|  2 | Te   |
|  3 | Jack |
|  4 | John |
```

The array has  somePGArray := [1,3], so a psuedo-query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE id NOT IN (somePGArray)
```

Resulting query:

```
|  people   |
-------------
| id | Name |
-------------
|  2 | Te   |
|  4 | John |
```

As a bonus, I also have no idea how to create an array and append ID's to it, so if you have a quick hint how to do that, that'd be tremendously helpful. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create table foo1 ( id integer, name text );
insert into foo1 values (1,'Bob'),(2,'Te'),(3,'Jack'),(4,'John');
select * from foo1 where id not in (1,2);
select * from foo1 where not (id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2]));

create or replace function so_example(int)
returns SETOF foo1 as $$
declare
  id alias for $1;
  idlist int[] := '{1}';
  q text;
  rec record;
begin
  idlist := idlist || ARRAY[id];
  q := 'select * from foo1 where not (id = ANY('||quote_literal(idlist)||'))';
  raise notice 'foo % %', idlist,q;
  for rec in execute(q) loop
    return next rec;
  end loop;
end; $$
language 'plpgsql';

select * from so_example(3);
```

Comment: Sweet, sounds like we're on to something...really quick, could you give a one-liner example of how to create that initial array, and maybe append an ID to it?

Comment: @btelles: Added example function to run the query and dynamically add values to it.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the square braces:

```
WHERE id NOT IN (1,2)
```

As a bonus, your NOT IN clause could be populated with a subquery that would look like:

```
Where id not in (select id from sometable where some_field = somevalue)
```

You could also do a dynamic string concatenation to generate a comma-separated set and inject it into an ad hoc query.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but I really need that thing to be an array as it gets created dynamically when the stored procedure runs. I've clarified the question to reflect this.

Comment: Plz see my edit. Can you use a subquery?if have a true array you could populate a temp table with those values and do a subselect on it.

Comment: Sorry man, I really need that array to be an array because of the structure of the stored procedure. (There are a few issues with it being a PostGIS query that do not allow for a subquery to find the necessary IDs.

Comment: Generating the query dynamically is also an option. Plz see other edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about an actual PostgreSQL [array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html), use

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE NOT id = ANY ('{1,3}')
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too familiar with arrays in PostgreSQL, but I need one, and I think you're on the right track. I definitely need to add elements to the array on the fly, could you explain how to do that?

Comment: The array-related functions are documented [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html). `array_append` or the `||` operator are probably what you're looking for. On sufficiently new versions, [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) could also be useful.

Comment: how to do for string array?